# Can't get around "Unknown Column In Field List" in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a search script which searches in `table1.title` to match titles to search queries and orders them based on score but I also want it to search and compare in `table2.title`. When I try to add `table2.title` to the script I get a `Unknown Column` error. It seems as if the script is rooted in `table1` and can't get information from other tables.

Here is the code of the search script:

```
"SELECT * , CASE WHEN table1.title OR table2.title LIKE 
'%".mysql_real_escape_string(like($_GET['search']), $db)."%' 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as score , MATCH table1.title AGAINST    
('".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search'], $db)."') 
AS score2 FROM table1 WHERE 1=1 AND MATCH (table1.title) AGAINST     
('".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search'], $db)."') ".
"ORDER BY table1.priority DESC , score DESC, score2 DESC  ".
"LIMIT ".(($page - 1) * $pp).", {$pp} ",
$db
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `CASE WHEN table1.title OR table2.title LIKE 
'%".mysql_real_escape_string(like($_GET['search']), $db)."%'` isn't going to do what you imagine

Comment: Now stop injecting $_GET vars directly into SQL queries, or little bobby tables will eat your site

Comment: ^-- Where's that PacMan icon when you need it.

Comment: Well, what is table2?  You have no reference to it in your `FROM` clause yet you are attempting to use `table2.title` column

Comment: Oh, and what's the point of `1=1` in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @ Mark Baker: Thanks I will update the code to stop SQL injection. Could you answer my question?

Comment: You should really use [PDO prepared statements](http://hu1.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). Your current mysql driver is obsolete... Please edit your post and write a PDO template instead of this mixed php - sql code!